# How to query in MySQL all entries with related categories

Tags: entries, categories, mysql, content

I have a custom product grid not associated with Craft Commerce. I am wondering, how can I query, in the SQL database, all entries and their related categories?

Comment: why would you write an SQL query instead of using craft techniques? (twig / element api)

Comment: Automated reporting purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `relations` table holds all of the information about relations between Craft elements (entries and categories in your case).

So you would use the `sourceId` and `targetId` columns of the `relations` table and join on the `id` columns of the `entries` and `categories` tables in your example.